# Docker & Graylog

Tags: docker, graylog2, graylog

I've been installing the last version of Docker (1.8). 
This new version is great because you can set a particular log-driver to send the log to Graylog2 (for example).

Here's the blog post from docker : [Docker Blog announcing 1.8](http://blog.docker.com/2015/08/docker-1-8-content-trust-toolbox-registry-orchestration/)
Here's the graylog team blog to make the magic happen : [Graylog blog](https://www.graylog.org/centralize-your-docker-container-logging-with-graylog-native-integration/)

My problem is that it doesn't work :(

Here is the error message I get when I lauch this command :

```
docker run –log-driver=gelf –log-opt gelf-address=udp://127.0.0.1:12201 busybox echo Hello Graylog
```

Error :

```
Unable to find image '–log-driver=gelf:latest' locally repository name component must match "[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*"
```

Here's an screenshot :

[image]

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

Following the advices of smart people : It looks like the dash was not the good one.

Here's a paste of the correct command :

```
docker run --log-driver=gelf --log-opt gelf-address=udp://127.0.0.1:12201 busybox echo Hello Graylog
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write two dashes instead a single one: `... --log-driver=gelf --log-opt ...`

**EDIT**: In that blogpost it is written:

> The Docker plugins mechanism is now available in the new Docker [experimental channel](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/experimental).

You need to install the experimental docker version like:

```
curl -sSL https://experimental.docker.com/ | sh
```

Comment: What does `docker version` say?

Comment: Client:
 Version:      1.8.0
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0d03096
 Built:        Tue Aug 11 16:48:39 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.0
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0d03096
 Built:        Tue Aug 11 16:48:39 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: You need to install the experimental version. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm now in 1.9.0-dev and I still get the same message.

Comment: BTW : Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: It should be in the stable release, but the problem is you need two dashes and @h3nrik suggests. Also, I'm not sure if that IP will work, you may need to use the IP of the host.

Comment: There is no way you will get the same error if you use `--`; it should say ` no log driver named 'gelf' is registered` if the driver isn't present.

Comment: Well... I do, I just added a screenshot so that you trust me ;)

Comment: Can you please do that again with a cut and paste rather than a screenshot? Unless you're using the wrong sort of dash, this seems very strange.

Comment: Yeah, you're using the wrong kind of dash :) Cut and paste the text from @h3nrik's answer and you'll see what I mean. You can even the see the difference in the question, compare the dash in the middle of the word to the dash at the start.

Comment: @AdrianMouat Wooow ! I'm impressed... did not even know there was 2 sorts of dash ! BRAVO !